# Problems with white-space/scrolling in ios mobile view

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, whitespace

all...

I'm working on: http://mercifulministries.com/index2.html, and `overflow-x:hidden` worked perfectly to remove whitespace on the left and right sides in browser view. Unfortunately, when viewed on a mobile device, you have to scroll a long way to the right to see the site. I've tried all sorts of overflow options, and tried to adapt to mobile via:

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {

        body {
            width:100%;
            overflow-x:hidden;
        }

}
```

but to no avail. What should I try next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldnt post external links, you should paste here the minimal code to reproduce the error and perhaps a JSFiddle or similar. If your link falls down in any future (which is likely to happen), then this question will be useless for future visitors.

Comment: I honestly don't know what the problem is, so I'm not able to narrow it down in the code.